# react-select change singleValue color based on options

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I would like to modify the 'selected' `singleValue` color in my `styles` object based on the options that are provided.

```
  const statusOptions = [
    { value: "NEW", label: i18n._(t`NEW`) },
    { value: "DNC", label: i18n._(t`DNC`) },
    { value: "WON", label: i18n._(t`WON`) },
    { value: "LOST", label: i18n._(t`LOST`) },
  ];
```

For example, if the option selected in "NEW", I want the font color to be red, if it's "WON", then green, and so on.  I am having trouble putting an `if` statement into the styles object. I see that its simple to put a ternary statement in, but how to you add more "complex" logic?

```
  const customStyles = {
    ...
    singleValue: (provided) => ({  
      ...provided,
      color: 'red' <----- something like if('NEW') { color: 'green' } etc..
    })
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an style map object:

```
import React from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';

const statusOptions = [
  { value: 'NEW', label: 'NEW' },
  { value: 'DNC', label: 'DNC' },
  { value: 'WON', label: 'WON' },
  { value: 'LOST', label: 'LOST' },
];

const styleMap = {
  NEW: 'red',
  DNC: 'blue',
};

const colourStyles = {
  singleValue: (provided, { data }) => ({
    ...provided,
    color: styleMap[data.value] ? styleMap[data.value] : 'defaultColor',
    // specify a fallback color here for those values not accounted for in the styleMap
  }),
};

export default function SelectColorThing() {
  return (
    <Select
      options={statusOptions}
      styles={colourStyles}
    />
  );
}
```